# Android: How to send unicode sms programatically and receive it on the other side correctly?

Tags: android, sms

I am using simple code to send sms:

```
SmsManager.getDefault().
  sendTextMessage(phone, null, "English characters", sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

And all works fine.

But when I send sms message in russinan language, using this code:

```
SmsManager.getDefault().
 sendTextMessage(phone, null, "Русский текст", sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

I receive on the other emulator something like this: `*&^#R*)@#_(&)@U(RH#*(&()^`

How can I fix it?
Please, help.

Comment: Tried using sendMultipartTextMessage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem of emulator. I use `SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage()` method for sending Russian text, and no real user report about any problems. Try on real device please.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you have to properly create the string.

For example:

```
new String("Русский текст", "UTF-16BE");
```

Watch out with your source code file. Normally it is safer to add the unicode character codes like \u0000. Otherwise you must always make sure you save your source code in UTF16 format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not help too.

BUT!!! I found another problem!

Locale is set to russian and the language is set to russian too, but

Comment: but i cant send sms correctly even from standard messaging program in emulator!

Comment: Doing a quick Google using the keywords "Android unicode sms" came up with some people having issues also with unicode. Some appear to be operator related and some to Android.

Comment: This makes no sense. 1) If your source code was UTF-16 encoded, then `"Русский текст"` would already be UTF-16 encoded before being converted to a Java String 2) You can use any encoding for your source code, as long as `javac` knows what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems like an emulator bug. This question migrated to another one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901477/android-receiving-another-bytes-after-sending-sms

Comment: @Jin35 you can't mark your own answer as accepted to your own question for a period of time (24-48 hours i think)